# how Android source code minify and obfuscate?

Tags: java, android, minify

I had done my apps, any idea to minify the Android and Java code?
can it save the apk file size and improve performance? compare to unminify source code.

Comment: is that i need to type:
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt in project.properties?

i try exported, but it get error:
there were 269 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2012-12-02 21:56:41 - com.crossrt.showtime.Main]
You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Enable shrinkResources in your build type. Note that it requires minify to be enabled.
In your Gradle file:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}
```

The accepted answer is now outdated, so I added this answer if someone else stumbles upon this question.

Comment: Can I use that option when I'm already using proguard/dexguard ?

Comment: If you update Gradle to the latest version proguard shouldn't even work. It changed name to minify, so you can't use them both since they are the same thing. For more info, see here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Comment: @Rickard I guess something changed in last few years. Now [this example](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-code) from Android official documentation has both `minifyEnabled` and `proguardFiles`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use ProGuard for this. Note however that your code will be obfuscated when it comes to crash reports etc so you need to keep obfuscation maps to be able to retrieve the stack traces between versions etc.
It does however protect you a lot better from reverse engineering your .APK.

More info@Android Developers:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Thx ya, but i get error:
You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
how should i fix it?

Comment: This answer is now old. Newer versions of Gradle does it without Proguard. Look up shrinkResources, or see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are three part

1. minifyEnabled
2. useProguard
3. shrinkResources

if you want to remove unused part of coding then you can use **`shrinkResources true`**

if you don't want to use default files like `dmp.txt`,`mapping.txt`,`seeds.txt`,`usage.txt` etc then you should use **`useProguard false`**

if you want to shrink your code and resource then you have to use **`minifyEnabled true`**

for more details [refer this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

Answer (score 3):

Just enable [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), it shrinks and obfuscates your application. It is included with the Android developer tools.

Comment: +1 for ProGuard. Just one note for OP: you do not want to reduce reduce your source code. You want to reduce your byte code. This is what ProGuard and other obfuscation tools do.

Comment: Thx ya, but i get error:
You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
how should i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[Minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) makes little sense in non scripting languages. What you can do is to use ProGuard to i.e. remove unused portions of the code, but as the major bloater in Android application are usually resources (drawables), ensure you do not have i.e. too many of them, or too big in size.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and i disable instant run

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
```

in proguard-rules.pro

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to optimize your code, use the
`proguard-android.txt` configuration file instead of `proguard-android-optimize.txt`. If you want to optimize code note optimization has certain risks, such as not all optimizations work well on all versions of dalvik VM.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Can you kindly edit your answer and explain why your source can help anyone regarding this 8 years old question?

Comment: Thanks for giving feedback